# Protected Excel workbook broken after pasting data from a "newer" workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, spreadsheet-protection

Given an excel workbook with an unlocked cell in a protected worksheet.

If I **copy a cell from another workbook which was opened after target workbook**, and paste it to the unlocked cell, it **becomes locked and I can't do anything** with it except undo the paste action.

On the other hand, if **source workbook was opened before the target, copy-paste works as expected - target cell remains editable**.

I've reproduced this on excel 2007 and 2010.

What am I asking is to reproduce the problem and advise how to handle this issue with VBA to avoid locking cells by users.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem but it sounds like a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro could `.Unprotect` then set `Target.Locked = False` and `.Protect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Jeeped advise, I wrote this script and it works:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Sh.Unprotect Password:="pwd"
Target.Locked = False
Sh.Protect Password:="pwd"
End Sub
```

But there's a side effect. Undo cache will be cleared each time worksheet changes.